java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.VariantVal
I evaluate Spark 4 try_variant_get method handling variant type data. First I make sql statements examples.
CREATE TABLE family (
  id INT,
  data VARIANT
);


INSERT INTO family (id, data)
VALUES
(1, PARSE_JSON('{"name":"Alice","age":30}')),
(2, PARSE_JSON('[1,2,3,4,5]')),
(3, PARSE_JSON('42'));

When SQL is executed, no errors are brought. Then Below codes are the select command using try_variant_get method
SELECT
  id,
  try_variant_get(data, '$.name', 'STRING') AS name,
  try_variant_get(data, '$.age', 'INT') AS age
FROM
  family
WHERE 
  try_variant_get(data, '$.name', 'STRING') IS NOT NULL;

SQL output is successfully returned. Then I transform these SQL statements into java api codes.
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("VariantExample").getOrCreate();

StructType schema = new StructType()
       .add("id", DataTypes.IntegerType)
       .add("data", DataTypes.VariantType);

Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(
       Arrays.asList(
            RowFactory.create(1, "{\"name\":\"Alice\",\"age\":30}"),
            RowFactory.create(2, "[1,2,3,4,5]"),
            RowFactory.create(3, "42")
       ),
       schema
);

 Dataset<Row> df_sel = df.select(
            col("id"),
            try_variant_get(col("data"), "$.name", "String").alias("name"),
            try_variant_get(col("data"), "$.age", "Integer").alias("age")
        ).where("name IS NOT NULL");

df_sel.printSchema();
df_sel.show();

But these java codes throw the following exceptions.
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.VariantVal (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.VariantVal is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.variant.VariantGet.nullSafeEval(variantExpressions.scala:282)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.eval(Expression.scala:692)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(InterpretedMutableProjection.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$48.$anonfun$applyOrElse$83(Optimizer.scala:2231)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:247)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:79).....

The "String" parameter of try_variant_get method has some problems. But I have no idea what is wrong with these java codes.  Kindly inform me how to fix these errors.

When you run createDataFrame() part, have you verified the data is inserted as expected, like when you inserted manually? Does select still work? If so, then we can isolate the problem only to the df.select() part

Thanks for your reply. createDataFrame() part works without error. df.show() codes bring successful results. I agree the problem is related with df.select() part. Especially try_variant_get() method.

In your Java code, you're constructing a DataFrame with the data column as a String instead of the expected Variant type, causing a ClassCastException.
We use try_parse_json() to handle the conversion of JSON strings into a format compatible with try_variant_get.
Solution:
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class VariantExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[*]")
            .appName("VariantExample")
            .getOrCreate();

        // Define schema with String type for input data
        StructType schema = new StructType()
            .add("id", DataTypes.IntegerType)
            .add("data", DataTypes.StringType);

        // Create DataFrame with raw string data
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(
            Arrays.asList(
                RowFactory.create(1, "{\"name\":\"Alice\",\"age\":30}"),
                RowFactory.create(2, "[1,2,3,4,5]"),
                RowFactory.create(3, "42")
            ),
            schema
        );

        // Convert 'data' column to JSON-compatible format using try_parse_json()
        Dataset<Row> dfWithParsedJson = df.withColumn("data", expr("try_parse_json(data)"));

        // Use try_variant_get to extract fields
        Dataset<Row> df_sel = dfWithParsedJson.select(
                col("id"),
                expr("try_variant_get(data, '$.name', 'STRING')").alias("name"),
                expr("try_variant_get(data, '$.age', 'INT')").alias("age")
            )
            .where("name IS NOT NULL");

        // Show results
        df_sel.printSchema();
        df_sel.show();
    }
}

Good luck!

Everything works successfully. But the to_variant() function you suggest does not exists in pySpark api. So I use try_parse_json() function and no exceptions are thrown. I appreciate your correct reply. ;)

I'm really glad you were able to use try_parse_json() successfully to resolve the issue and I hope my initial explanation still helped guide you in the right direction.
Let me fix the answer so it may help people of future :D
